# How to extract specfic data from lines in a text file and output to a new text file using C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have several large .csv files that contain lines of data. I need to extract from each line only specific parts of the data, thereby ignoring the parts I am not interested in and output the result into a new text file.

For example, here is a section of the data:

```
Fr 23:59:59 M40 N04161K RX LAG 2 JNYT  17 STORE OCC 1 PRUD 1 RAW  -9 LAG   0

Fr 23:59:59 M08  N09461M  %SAT   3  %CONG   0  MQ 0  EB 0  OSQ     0 NSQ     4

Fr 23:59:59 M20 N09461M SAT   3%  SQ     0  FLOW     4  GN  13  STOC  9
```

I am looking to write a new file that looks like this:

```
5,23,59,59,2,17,1,1,-9,0

5,23,59,59,3,0,0,0,0,4

5,23,59,59,3,0,4,13,9
```

(You will notice that the start of the data is a '5' which I would also like to use instead of 'Fr' which stands for 'Friday')

The data is identified in datasets by the 'M' reference (M40, M08 etc) and it would be useful to output all the data in its dataset (so for example all data with M40 filtered into one .txt file, hence my 'if' statements)

I would prefer to have each number separated with a comma but not essential

Here is my code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String line;
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\MessExport_20110402_0000.csv");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\output.txt");
            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("M40"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
                    if (line.Contains("M08"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }      
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the files
            sr.Close();
            sw.Close();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

It would then be useful to read the next .csv file and again output the results to a new .txt file

I am very new to using any code with regex and split so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything to do with actually splitting the code yourself, or is this all of the related code you have?
[Also, split is a relatively easy method, even if you're new. I would give it a read over since it should accomplish what you're looking for.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) In my opinion, messing with regex is a little more confusing, especially if you don't have a grip on basic string functions like split.

Comment: I would suggest you to check the **LastIndexOf()** Method, the **SubString()** Method and add a couple of **if**s in order to work with the data. I asume that is a tab separated value so you should start to think that you have to parse each line and, since every line has the same amount of columns, ignore specific substrings.

Comment: What would make most sense is to use `string.Split` and the `TryParse` functions to convert each record into a new instance of a record class. This class would then contain a meaningful representation of the data with variable names representing each of the data fields. You can then easily use LINQ to select and group the records however you want. All you then need is a method that takes a collection of elements and writes them to a file. With these components, you should be able to build a nicely structured and re-usable piece of code to manipulate your data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, very useful. I originally had a solution using Matlab, however the code was taking a very long time to execute and was not feasible, since I have several million lines of data to extract. So I wanted to try to see if C# offered a more efficient solution

Comment: My plan might not be great for huge sets of data, as it involves storing the whole set in memory before writing to a file. For that case, you'd be better off processing the records separately without storing any intermediate representation.

Comment: Especially with millions of lines and the fact that you are looking for an efficient solution, it might be a good idea to look into multithreading, depending on of it would be worth it in your situation.  
Also, keep in mind that you DO NOT want to be creating unnecessary new strings while working with so much data. So just be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a straightforward implementation:

```
string workingDirectory = @"c:\";

var days = new[] { "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa" };
var writers = new Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(workingDirectory + "data.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var items = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        StreamWriter w;
        if (!writers.TryGetValue(items[2], out w))
        {
            w = new StreamWriter(workingDirectory + items[2] + ".txt");
            writers.Add(items[2], w);
        }

        var times = items[1].Split(':');
        var digits = items.Skip(3)
                    .Select(x => { int i; return new { IsValid = int.TryParse(x, out i), Value = x }; })
                    .Where(x => x.IsValid).Select(x => x.Value);
        var data = new[] { Array.IndexOf(days, items[0]).ToString() }.Concat(times).Concat(digits);
        w.WriteLine(String.Join(",", data));
    }
}
foreach (var w in writers)
{
    w.Value.Close();
    w.Value.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This works superbly for one file...brilliant and so appreciated! How would I add a simple loop to read multiple files in the same way and either add the output data to the same dataset (e.g. M40, M08 etc) or if it's easier create more separate files?

Comment: Put this code in a method with 2 string parameters - input file and output files prefix (or suffix). Use suffix to form output files names: workingDirectory + items[2] + "_" + suffix + ".txt"     Than call this method in a loop.

Comment: That's excellent - I had the same type of solution in Matlab but wasn't sure if it would work in C# - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick stab, but I think it will get you part of the way there.

```
var lines = new List<string> { 
    "Fr 23:59:59 M40 N04161K RX LAG 2 JNYT  17 STORE OCC 1 PRUD 1 RAW  -9 LAG   0",
    "Fr 23:59:59 M08  N09461M  %SAT   3  %CONG   0  MQ 0  EB 0  OSQ     0 NSQ     4",
    "Fr 23:59:59 M20 N09461M SAT   3%  SQ     0  FLOW     4  GN  13  STOC  9"
};
var options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
var regex = new Regex("(?: ^\\w\\w | -?\\b\\d+\\b )", options );

foreach (var l in lines ){
    var matches = regex.Matches( l );

    foreach(Match m in matches){
        Console.Write( "{0},", m.Value );
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Produces:

```
Fr,23,59,59,2,17,1,1,-9,0,
Fr,23,59,59,3,0,0,0,0,4,
Fr,23,59,59,3,0,4,13,9,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Program
{
  public class TransformCsv
  {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      (new TransformCsv()).Run(@"c:\temp\MessExport_20110402_0000.csv", @"c:\temp\output.txt", LineFilterFunction);
    }

    public static Boolean LineFilterFunction(String line)
    {
      return line.Contains("M40") || line.Contains("M08");
    }

    ////////////////////

    private List<String> _dayOfWeek = new List<String>() { "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su" };

    private Dictionary<String, String> _mReference =
      new Dictionary<String, String>()
      {
        // Add other M-reference mappings here.
        { "M40", "2" },
        { "M08", "3" },
        { "M20", "3" }
      };

    public void Run(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, Func<String, Boolean> lineFilterFunction)
    {
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath))
      {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
        {
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && lineFilterFunction(line))
              writer.WriteLine(this.GetTransformedLine(line));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private static Char[] _spaceCharacter = " ".ToCharArray();

    private String GetTransformedLine(String line)
    {
      var elements = line.Split(_spaceCharacter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      var result = new List<String>();
      result.Add((_dayOfWeek.IndexOf(elements[0]) + 1).ToString());
      result.Add(elements[1].Replace(':', ','));
      result.Add(_mReference[elements[2]]);
      result.AddRange(elements.Skip(3).Where(e => this.IsInt32(e)));

      return String.Join(",", result);
    }

    private Boolean IsInt32(String s)
    {
      Int32 _;
      return Int32.TryParse(s, out _);
    }
  }
}
```